# How do you change the font size in HTML/css without the div size changing?

Tags: html, css

When I change the text size in the div (id="home"), it also changes the size of the div. I want to be able to change the text size without the div size changing every time.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link type="html/css" rel="stylesheet" href="websiteCSS.css"/>
        <title>PROTOTYPE</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="sidebar"></div>
        <div id="home" class="header">Home</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0; 
    background: #d5e9d7;
}

#sidebar {
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    #background-color: light blue;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #545454 0%, #424242 100%);
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 2.5em;
    height: 1em;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #b2b2b2;
    margin-top: 0.5%;
    margin-left: 20.5%;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #333333;
}

.header:hover {
    font-size: 2.1em;
}
```

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue. And I cannot pre-determine the height of my div. I need it to be set to the height that it would be if the font was already that big. I'm having hover effects to increase the font size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set your div size in `px` or set a `min-width` or `min-height` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Set the container div (width and height) to be able to hold the worst case (biggest) font size. This will stop the div resizing depending on font size.